# Protect folder outside wordpress install with wordpress login session?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, authentication

I need some way to protect a folder that is not part of the wordpress install that has sensitive content that only logged in users should be able to access.

I've seen ways of doing a htaccess cookie protection but how secure is this, isn't the cookie displayed in browser and could be figured out and manufactured without logging in? (I'm no expert obviously).

I wonder if there's any easy solutions to protect a folder and its content with the worpdress user session? Any ideas?